# Pwa notification with js

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

why my pwa don't working? I need get notification.

```
 // Проверка поддержки и регистрация Service Worker
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
          .then(registration => {
            console.log('Service Worker зарегистрирован:', registration);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('Ошибка регистрации Service Worker:', err);
          });
      }
    
      let latestArticleId = 0;
    
      // Загрузка новостей при загрузке страницы и каждые 10 секунд
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        loadData();
        setInterval(loadData, 10000);
    
        // Обработчик нажатия на кнопку для запроса разрешения на уведомления
        const enableNotificationsButton = document.getElementById('enable-notifications');
        enableNotificationsButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            Notification.requestPermission().then(permission => {
                if (permission === "granted") {
                    console.log("Разрешение на уведомления получено");
                    enableNotificationsButton.style.display = 'none'; // Скрыть кнопку после получения разрешения
                }
            });
        });
    });
    
    
    // Запрос новостей с сервера или из кеша
      function loadData() {
        fetch('/api/news')
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Ошибка сетевого запроса');
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(data => {
            if (data.items.length > 0) {
              updateNewsList(data.items);
              checkForNewArticle(data.items);
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Ошибка при получении новостей:', error);
            loadFromCache();
          });
      }
    
      // Обновление списка новостей на странице
      function updateNewsList(articles) {
        const newsContainer = document.getElementById('news-container');
        newsContainer.innerHTML = '';
        articles.slice(0,10).forEach(article => {
          const articleElem = document.createElement('div');
          articleElem.className = 'news-article';
          articleElem.innerHTML = `<h3>${article.title}</h3><p>Опубликовано ${article.author} в ${article.publicationDate}</p>`;
          newsContainer.appendChild(articleElem);
        });
      }
    
      // Проверка наличия новых статей
      function checkForNewArticle(articles) {
        if (articles[0].id > latestArticleId) {
          latestArticleId = articles[0].id;
          if (document.hidden) {
            showNotification(articles[0].title);
          }
        }
      }
    
      // Отображение уведомлений
      function showNotification(title) {
        if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
          new Notification("Новая статья!", {
            body: title,
            icon: '/icons/icon-192x192.png'
          });
        } else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
          Notification.requestPermission().then(permission => {
            if (permission === "granted") {
              new Notification("Новая статья!", {
                body: title,
                icon: '/icons/icon-192x192.png'
              });
            }
          });
        }
      }
    
      // Загрузка новостей из кеша
      function loadFromCache() {
        if (!navigator.serviceWorker) {
          console.log('Service Worker не поддерживается этим браузером.');
          return;
        }
    
        navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({ type: 'get-cached-news' });
    
        navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = event => {
          if (event.data.type === 'cached-news' && event.data.articles) {
            updateNewsList(event.data.articles);
          }
        };
      }
```

it`s my code, why I don't get message for accept notification/ it`s pwa for get 10 last news from server, and when server pushing  new news, I need get notification from browser or pwa app. it`s my code, why I don't get message for accept notification/ it`s pwa for get 10 last news from server, and when server pushing  new news, I need get notification from browser or pwa app.

Comment: do you see any information in the browser developer tools console, or, errors perhaps? Have you tried any sort of debugging at all?

Comment: there are no errors, the notification permission request function is just not called

Comment: perhaps `Notification.permission` is `denied` ... you have not tested for that. Your code is running in a secure context, right?